# How do I extract specific information from my POST request payload and save into a txt file?

Tags: node.js, post, request

Hi I would like to know any method that Im able to use to extract only the ‘result’ part of it into a txt file. The payload is extracted from a POST Request from a device to my own server. Example:

```
{
  "cid": "042071004033",
  "time": 1593673402,
  "front_vaule": 94,
  "scale_out_x": 1,
  "scale_out_y": 0.5,
  "sharpen_ness": 89,
  "track_id": 155,
  "type": 1,
  "upload_face_size": 120,
  "upload_id": 8,
  "result": {
    "person_id": 123456,
    "person_name": "",
    "age": 0,
    "sex": "male",
    "temperature": 37,
    "confidence": 0,
    "person_type": 0,
    "facemask": 1
  }
```

And the only JSON payload I would want to save to the txt file is

```
    "person_id": "",
    "person_name": "",
    "age": 0,
    "sex": "male",
    "temperature": 37,
    "confidence": 0,
    "person_type": 0,
    "facemask": 1
```

Below is my current code please tell me where to insert your suggested code thanks.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = express.Router();

var fs = require('fs');

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 1000000 }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 1000000 }));

app.post('/face', (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST');
    //console.log(req.body);
    data = req.body;
    //console.log(data);
    res.status(200).json('200OK');
    //string data from JSON to txt and overwrite existing txt data
    var data = JSON.stringify(data.result, null, 2);    
    //console.log(data.result.person_id);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${data.result.person_id}-database.txt`, data, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error logging data to txt file!');
        } else {
            console.log('Logged into text file successfully!');
        }
    })
});


const server = app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('server listening on port', server.address().port);
});
```

Error Log:

```
POST
TypeError: Cannot read property 'person_id' of undefined
    at C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\server.js:20:37
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:82:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\gohyu\Desktop\nodetestapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to just do `JSON.stringify(data.result)`. It's a simple object though.

Comment: oh yes thank you im able to get the result however is it possible to create a new txt file for every new submission?

Comment: Sure. You can choose some unique identifier for your file name like the person_id (if this is unique, else you can use something else like the current timestamp?) for example: ``fs.writeFileSync(`${data.result.person_id}-database.txt`, data, done)``

Comment: i have tried apply this however im getting this error : 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'person_id' of undefined'

Comment: Looks like the `result` field is missing in the response. Can you print out the whole `data` and see what's missing.

Comment: tried to console log data.result.person_id and data.person_id but to no avail

Comment: Great! :-) happy to help somehow, hopefully!